# Compactness of subset of trace-class operators on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

Consider an infinite-dimensional, complex and separable Hilbert space $H$ and let  $\mathcal I(H)$ denote the space of trace-class operators.

The set of density operators is defined by $$\mathcal S(H):=\{\rho\in\mathcal I(H)\,|\,\mathrm{Tr}\rho =1\,,\, \rho\geq 0 \}\quad .$$

**Question:** Is it true that $\mathcal S(H)$ is compact with respect to the weak$^*$-topology?

---

Here are my ideas: I think it holds that weak$^*$-closed and norm bounded subsets of $\mathcal I(H)$ are weak$^*$-compact and vice versa, correct? Then, since $\mathcal S(H)$ is (trace-)norm bounded, I tried to prove that it is also weak$^*$-closed to arrive at the desired result.

To this end, I proved that if $(\rho_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with $\rho_n\in\mathcal S(H)$ converges in the weak$^*$ sense ($\mathrm{Tr}\rho_n A\to \mathrm{Tr}\rho A$ for all compact $A$) to some $\rho\in \mathcal I(H)$, then $\rho \geq 0$, which follows from picking one-dimensional projectors $A=|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$ for $\psi\in H$. I failed however in proving that the trace condition holds.

Perhaps there is a smarter way in proving the assertion (if it is true)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice observations. It is not true that $S(H)$ is compact, though. The element $0$ is in the weak$^*$-closure of $S(H)$, while not being in $S(H)$. Concretely, fix an orthonormal basis $\{\psi_k\}$ and let $e_k$ be the corresponding rank-one projections (that is, $e_k\eta=\langle \eta,\psi_k\rangle\,\psi_k$, or $e_k=|\psi_k\rangle\langle\psi_k|$ if you prefer bra-ket notation). We have that $e_k\in S(H)$ for all $k$, and we also have that $e_k\to0$ in the weak$^*$-topology.

---

**Edit:** I cannot think of an entirely straightforward argument to show that $e_k\to0$ weak$^*$. So here it is. We want to show that $\def\tr{\operatorname{Tr}}\tr(e_kT)\to0$ for all compact $T$.

The first reduction is to see that it is enough to assume that $T\geq0$. This comes from using Hölder's inequality:
$$
|\tr(e_kT)|^2=|\tr(Te_k)|^2\leq\tr(e_kT^*Te_k)\tr(e_k)=\tr(e_kT^*T).
$$

Next, we may assume that $T$ is positive and finite-rank. Because if $T$ is an arbitrary positive compact operator, by the Spectral Theorem we can find positive finite-rank operators $T_n$ with $\|T_n-T\|\to0$.  Then
$$
|\tr(e_k(T_n-T))|\leq\|T_n-T\|\,\tr(e_k)=\|T_n-T\|. 
$$
So given $\def\e{\varepsilon}\e>0$ we can choose $n$ such that $\|T_n-T\|<\e$. And we can choose $k_0$ such that for all $k\geq k_0$ we have that $|\tr(e_kT_n)|<\e$. Then for all $k\geq k_0$ we have
$$
|\tr(e_kT)|\leq|\tr(e_k(T-T_n))|+|\tr(e_kT_n)|<2\e.
$$

A positive, finite-rank compact operator is a linear combination of rank-one projections. So it is enough to show that $\tr(e_kP)\to0$ for a rank-one projection $P$. The projection $P$ is of the form $P\eta=\langle\eta,\psi\rangle\,\psi$ for a unit vector $\psi$. Then, calculating the trace through an orthonormal basis where $\psi$ is the first element,
$$
\tr(e_kP)=\langle e_k\,\psi,\psi\rangle=|\langle\psi,\psi_k\rangle|^2\to0
$$
by Bessel's Inequality.

Comment: Dear Martin, thank you very much for your detailed answer. Note that I am not a mathematician, so I have very limited background and I probably miss many important, well-known theorems and results. I have one question: You say that a positive compact operator can, by the spectral theorem, be approximated by positive finite-rank operators in the (operator) norm topology. But isn't the spectral theorem formulated within the strong operator topology (and usually convergence in SOT does not imply convergence in op. norm)? What am I missing?

Comment: Also, why can you choose $k$ s.t. $|\mathrm{Tr}(e_kT_n)|\leq \epsilon$? Is it also due to the Besell's inequality? I.e. $T_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha_i |u_i\rangle\langle v_i|$ for some orthonormal $\{u_i\}$ and $\{v_i\}$, and then $|\langle \psi_k, T_n \psi_k\rangle|\leq \sum\limits_i |\alpha_i| |\langle \psi_k|u_i\rangle | | \langle v_i|\psi_k\rangle|$ which should then, term by term, go to $0$ as $k\to \infty$ - correct?

Comment: No. Convergence in the Spectral Theorem is in norm. You can think of a positive compact operator as diagonal (it is, in the right orthonormal basis, which is precisely what the Spectral Theorem says). And the operator norm of a positive diagonal operator is the sup of the entries (the maximum in the case of a compact). In a compact positive operator, the diagonal decreases to zero. So if you "cut" the beginning of the diagonal, the rest can be made arbitrarily small by cutting late enough.

Comment: The choice of $k$ is because one is assuming that the result works for finite-rank operators, i.e. that $\operatorname{Tr}(e_k S)\to0$ if $S$ is finite-rank.

Comment: Ah, okay, so I have to read again about the spectral theorem for compact operators. Regarding the other point: Sorry to be pedantic, but why do you say assume? Is my reasoning in the previous comment not correct? In any case, thanks again for the effort -- much appreciated!

Comment: It is correct. It is also what the last paragraph in my answer says. But to me it is much easier to say that limits are linear, so if I prove it for one terms I have it proven for all terms in a linear combination.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathcal S(H)$ need not be weak* compact. Consider the operator sequence $(A_n)$ in $\mathcal S(\ell^2(\mathbb N))$:
$$A_n=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{n} &  & & & & & \\
 & \frac{1}{n} & & & & & \\
 & &  \ddots & & & & \\
 & & & \frac{1}{n} & & &\\
 & & & & 0 & &\\
& & & & & 0 & \\
& & & & & & \ddots  
\end{pmatrix}.$$
For any finite-rank operator $B$, we have
$$0\leq |\operatorname{Tr}(A_nB)|\leq \|A_n\|\operatorname{Tr}(|B|)=\frac{1}{n}\operatorname{Tr}(|B|) \to 0 \quad (n\to \infty).$$
For any compact operator $C$ and any $\epsilon>0$, take a finite-rank operator $B$ such that $\|B-C\|<\epsilon$, which follows that $|\operatorname{Tr}(A_nB)-\operatorname{Tr}(A_nC)|\leq \|B-C\|\operatorname{Tr}(|A_n|)<\epsilon$ for ALL $n$.
Consequently,
$\operatorname{Tr}(A_nC)$ converges to $0$ for any compact operator $C$. Therefore $A_n$ weak* converges to $0\notin \mathcal S(H)$.

Comment: Hi C. Ding, thanks for your answer. Indeed, $\mathcal S(H)$ is closed with respect to the trace-norm, but I think that I need to show it is closed with respect to the weak$^*$-topology in order to conclude it is a (weak$^*$-)closed subset of a (weak$^*$-)compact subset, no? If I am wrong here, would you mind to include a few more details (such as, stating the exact versions of theorems you use)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain why it is enough to consider only positive compact operators? Also, I think this is not quite correct, because you need that the trace of $B$ must exist, no? I am not a mathematician, so I have very limited background here, but I can imagine that there are positive, compact operators which are not of trace-class (or am I wrong?).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I think it makes sense now! Much appreciated.